# XSLT: add source XML to transformed XML as Text value

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform an XML to a different XML structure that also contains the original XML as value.

```xml
<root>
    <item>
        <a>Text&amp;A</a>
        <b>Text&amp;B</b>
        <c>Text&amp;C</c>
    </item>
    <item>
        <a>TextA</a>
        <b>TextB</b>
        <c>TextC</c>
    </item>
</root>
```

```xml
<root>
    <item>
        <ab>Text&amp;A Text&amp;B</ab>
        <orig>
            &lt;a&gt;Text&amp;amp;A&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;b&gt;Text&amp;amp;B&lt;/b&gt;
            &lt;c&gt;Text&amp;amp;C&lt;/c&gt;
        </orig>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ab>TextA TextB</ab>
        <orig>
            &lt;a&gt;TextA&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;b&gt;TextB&lt;/b&gt;
            &lt;c&gt;TextC&lt;/c&gt;
        </orig>
    </item>
</root>
```

The important part is the `orig` element which should contain a copy of the source XML as text. I do NOT know all the elements of the source XML. It may also include the `item` tag, that's not really relevant.
Can this be done with XSLT?

Answer (score 2):

The logic of the required transformation is not entirely clear, esp. with regard to the unknown elements. If your processor supports **XSLT 3.0**, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <ab>
            <xsl:value-of select="a, b"/>
        </ab>
        <orig>
            <xsl:value-of select="serialize(node())"/>
        </orig>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <item>
      <ab>Text&amp;A Text&amp;B</ab>
      <orig>
        &lt;a&gt;Text&amp;amp;A&lt;/a&gt;
        &lt;b&gt;Text&amp;amp;B&lt;/b&gt;
        &lt;c&gt;Text&amp;amp;C&lt;/c&gt;
    </orig>
   </item>
   <item>
      <ab>TextA TextB</ab>
      <orig>
        &lt;a&gt;TextA&lt;/a&gt;
        &lt;b&gt;TextB&lt;/b&gt;
        &lt;c&gt;TextC&lt;/c&gt;
    </orig>
   </item>
</root>
```

which is identical to the result you show.

Comment: Thx, that actually looks like it is exactly what I want. So far I can't get it to work though. I don't actually know what XSLT version is supported - I'm using it with some proprietary software. May have to find out what it actually uses for the XSLT...

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: If you're not able to install a processor that supports the serialize() function, there is a serializer written in XSLT 1.0 at http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl